# EF Core in-memory SQLite DB not reset

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a project that uses EF Core, and I'm trying to run unit tests. At the moment they fail when running 'all tests' since apparently the database is not properly reset between tests.

- Typically the first test in the list succeeds
- Other tests fail with errors such as:

  - unique key constraint fail (when seeding data... data already exists)
  - more rows are 'created' than expected for a test (because other rows from other tests are still there)
- When I run the tests one by one by hand they all succeed.

I'm using this code to created the context used in the tests:

```
public class SampleDbContextFactory : IDisposable
{
    private DbConnection _connection;

    private DbContextOptions<SampleDbContext> CreateOptions()
    {
        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(_connection).Options;
    }

    public SampleDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        if (_connection == null)
        {
            _connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            _connection.Open();

            var options = CreateOptions();
            using (var context = new SampleDbContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }

        return new SampleDbContext(CreateOptions());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Within a test, I call it like this:

```
using (var factory = new SampleDbContextFactory())
{
    using (var context = factory.CreateContext())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have experimented amongst other things with making _connection static, using EnsureDeleted before EnsureCreated,..

What could be the issue?

Comment: What type of project do you use this class in? Is it a web project? If yes, do you use WebApplicationFactory? If yes, how do you reset database for each test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem:

I had some seed object that was declared static. This kept the database alive over multiple tests. So make sure all of your seeded rows are new instances.